# Get Assembly where instance is declared in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, reflection

I have a `framework.dll`, `customerFramework.dll` and `customer.exe`.

Inside of the `framework.dll` is a `customControl` declared which can be placed in `customerFramework.dll` (in a `XAML` page/window) or in `customer.exe` (in a `XAML` page/window).

The `customControl` got a public `DependencyProperty` of type `Uri`. Visual Studio supports `IntelliSense` for its resources, so it is very easy to set these properties.

During runtime, the `CustomControl` tries to resolve the resources inside of `framework.dll`, but they are declared in:

1. `customer.exe`

   - To fix this issue, I have to set the following prefix: `/customer;component/ballon.svg`.
2. `customerFramework.dll`

   - To fix this issue, I have to set the following prefix: `/customerFramework;component/ballon.svg`.

But if I do so, I don't have any `IntelliSense`. So I would like to combine the right `uri` by adding the prefix in code behind.

[image: flowchart]

---

What I want to know is the assembly name inside of the `customControl`, where the `customControl` has been placed.

If the `customControl` is placed in `customerFramework.dll` and I use the `Assembly.()` methods, I get the wrong informations (**expected value: customerFramework**):

- `GetEntryAssembly()`: customer.exe
- `GetCallingAssembly()`: framework.dll
- `GetExecutingAssembly()`: framework.dll

Is there a hidden function to get this information?

---

Comment: Why should a control need to know the assembly where it is used? If you explain the reasoning behind this, we may perhaps provide an appropriate solution.

Comment: I have added a few more details why I need this information.

Comment: What kind of resources do you have? images?

Comment: `*.svg` as a `Resource`

Answer (score 1):

sorry man i misunderstood the question .

please use reflection with stacktrace

```
var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var callerAssemblies = new StackTrace().GetFrames()
                .Select(x => x.GetMethod().ReflectedType.Assembly).Distinct()
                .Where(x => x.GetReferencedAssemblies().Any(y => y.FullName == currentAssembly.FullName));
        var initialAssembly = callerAssemblies.Last();
```

Code will be slow because it use reflection . good luck.

Comment: `GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName` or `GetType().Assembly.FullName` are both giving me `framework.dll` as result. I expected `customer.exe` or `customerFramework.dll`

Comment: sorry i not read full question that time , i updated with proper one now :(

Comment: Ok I have tested it so far and it is not working. Thanks anyway for your try

Comment: what you getting  in initialAssembly ?